# Javascript Windows Print custom CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I need to print a page with `windows.print()`.
If I change the CSS before to call the print, the change is ignored.

How can I solve it?

**CSS**

```
@media print {
   .printOpt { color:white; }
}
```

**Javascript** (fired before print event)

```
$("#myDiv").addClass("printOpt");
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/TQaxd/

Comment: Do you have a stylesheet for print? You mean you change the CSS with JS or something?

Comment: Have you looked at using `@media print { ... }` within your CSS?

Comment: Just add `$(".myClass").css("color", "white");`.
I can see the change on the page but not on the printed page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define it beforehand inside your `<head></head>` tag, try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Use media="screen" for whats on screen and media="all" for both.
With this the browser knows which CSS to use for what.

Comment: This is my CSS
`@media print {.printOpt { color:white; }}`
and before to print 
`$("#myDiv").addClass("printOpt");` but it is not working